# Pass-through authentication for MS SQL 2005 DB from SharePoint?

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

Within our Active Directory domain, we have a MS SQL 2005 server, and a SharePoint (MOSS 3.0 I believe) server.  Both authenticate against our LDAP server.  Would like to allow these authenticated SharePoint visitors to see some of the data from the MS SQL database.  Primary challenge is authentication.

Any tips on getting the pass-through authentication to work?  I have searched (Google) for a proper connection string to use, but keep finding ones that have embedded credentials or other schemes.  I gather that SSPI is what I want to use, but am not sure how to implement.

clarification: we don't have a single-sign-on server (e.g. Shibboleth) setup yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using C# the code and connection string is:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient; 
... 
SqlConnection oSQLConn = new SqlConnection(); 
oSQLConn.ConnectionString = 
    "Data Source=(local);" + 
    "Initial Catalog=myDatabaseName;" +
    "Integrated Security=SSPI";
 //Or
 // "Server=(local);" + 
 // "Database=myDatabaseName;" + 
 // "Trusted_Connection=Yes";
oSQLConn.Open(); 
... 
oSQLConn.Close();
```

An excellent resource for connection strings can be found at [Carl Prothman's Blog](http://www.carlprothman.net/Default.aspx?tabid=81). Yoy should probably replace `(local)` with the name of the SQL server.

You will need to either configure SQL server to give the Domain Roles the access privilages you want. In SQL server you will need to go to Security\Logins and make sure you have the Domain\User Role (ie MyCompany\SharpointUsers). In your config you should have

Comment: These particular users have permissions (based on their LDAP LID) to view the SQL Server data, and are using an older application that accesses the SQL database directly.  Would like to tap into those same stored procedures from SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

Actually Windows Authentication verifies the user is legitimate without passing the username and password over the wire. Whereas Passthrough authentication does pass the username and password over the wire. They are not the same thing. Using the connection string and code provided by Leo Moore causes SQL to use Windows Authentication, which it uses by default - not Passthrough authentication, which the OP asked about.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "users of SharePoint"?

Do you mean that they want to see data from inside a SharePoint page?
In that case you have to do impersonation in that page/application, and possible set up Kerberos correctly.

Then you will have to assign those SharePoint users (or better, their AD group) proper privileges on the SQL Server.

Comment: The "users of SharePoint" are people logging into SharePoint to interact with its content.  They each have read-only access rights to the SQL Server so that is set up.  Kerberos might help but as I said it's not currently available.